# Wrap a Vertical bar with the Content

Tags: html, css, wrapper

i'm trying to wrap the content and a vertical bar. 
right now when the Viewport increate the Content and the Bar move away from each other (the Bar to the right and the Content to the left)
But i want them to Seperate to a specific amount and stay like that.
This is my Screendesign:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcD2R.jpg)

And that would be my Code right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        </div>

        <div id="navhm">
        </div>

        <div id="space">
        </div>
        <div id="wrapperres">
        <div id="pfosten">
        </div>

        <div id="contwrap">
        <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And thats my CSS
http://codepen.io/Blackcan/pen/AXovrL

Any Advices are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use flexbox for this.

Let's say your HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-left">
            <div class="nav-fixed">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-media">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then you could use in your CSS:

```
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .content-left {
        flex: 0 0 60vw;
        overflow-y: scroll;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .social-media {
        flex: 0 0 20vw;
    }

    .nav-fixed {
         flex: 0 0 40px;
    }
   .content {
        flex: 0 0 300px;
    }
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/J-DD/pen/QErjLE

More about flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

http://thenewcode.com/780/A-Designers-Guide-To-Flexbox

Comment: I see that seems pretty good like what i wanted. But the Boxes "scale" up do i see that right? like the width changes which will get a problem with using the wooden texture

Comment: Yes that's possible. The width of the boxes is set with `flex: 0 0 20vw`. 20vw stands for viewport width, so when your browsers scales, the boxes scale with it. You could also set a fixed value. Just edit 20vw. For example: `flex: 0 0 30px`.

You should change `.content-left` and `.social-media` to disable the scaling.

Comment: Oh i see! thank you a lot i'll use that one! Thank you very much :)